# Swift playground with dictionary too slow

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I have created a Swift playground with the following code in Xcode 7.1 and its evaluation is extremely slow (a few minutes usually). Why is this happening? As it makes the playground essentially unusable, can I do anything to improve its execution time?

```
let sets = [
    "TEMPERATURE":[
        (value:37.0, attributes:["A":0.0, "B":0.2]),
        (value:37.5, attributes:["A":0.0, "B":1.0]),
        (value:38.0, attributes:["A":0.2, "B":0.5]),
        (value:38.5, attributes:["A":0.5, "B":0.2]),
        (value:39.0, attributes:["A":0.8, "B":0.0]),
        (value:39.5, attributes:["A":1.0, "B":0.0]),
        (value:40.0, attributes:["A":1.0, "B":0.0]),
    ],
    "VARIATION":[
        (value:0.0, attributes:["A":0.0, "B":1.0]),
        (value:2.0, attributes:["A":0.2, "B":0.8]),
        (value:5.0, attributes:["A":0.5, "B":0.5]),
        (value:8.0, attributes:["A":0.8, "B":0.2]),
        (value:10.0, attributes:["A":1.0, "B":0.0]),
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the Swift compiler is very slow at deducing the type of `sets`. If you make the type explicit, the Swift compiler won't have to spend any time deducing it. Try this:

```
let sets: [String:[(value: Double, attributes:[String:Double])]] = [
    "TEMPERATURE":[
        (value:37.0, attributes:["A":0.0, "B":0.2]),
        (value:37.5, attributes:["A":0.0, "B":1.0]),
        (value:38.0, attributes:["A":0.2, "B":0.5]),
        (value:38.5, attributes:["A":0.5, "B":0.2]),
        (value:39.0, attributes:["A":0.8, "B":0.0]),
        (value:39.5, attributes:["A":1.0, "B":0.0]),
        (value:40.0, attributes:["A":1.0, "B":0.0]),
    ],
    "VARIATION":[
        (value:0.0, attributes:["A":0.0, "B":1.0]),
        (value:2.0, attributes:["A":0.2, "B":0.8]),
        (value:5.0, attributes:["A":0.5, "B":0.5]),
        (value:8.0, attributes:["A":0.8, "B":0.2]),
        (value:10.0, attributes:["A":1.0, "B":0.0]),
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try appending `"VARIATION"` after `sets`'s initialisation. If this is still slow, keep narrowing it down to append smaller and smaller bits to the larger dictionary. I know this is tedious, but unfortunately this can be a common error with Xcode and long amounts of data.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This improved execution time as well, but by setting the type explicitly as rob described it took even less time to initialize my playground.